# min function only printing one result instead of two

Tags: python-2.7, min

```
def Skew(Text):    
    skew = {}
    n = len(Text)
    skew[0] = 0
    for i in range(1,n+1):   
        #Every time we encounter a G, skew[i] is equal to skew[i-1]+1
        if Text[i-1] == "G": skew[i] = skew[i-1]+1
        #every time we encounter a C, Skew[i] is equal to Skew[i-1]-1
        elif Text[i-1] == "C": skew[i] = skew[i-1]-1
        #otherwise, Skew[i] is equal to Skew[i-1]
        else: skew[i] = skew[i-1]
return skew


Text = "CCGGCCGG"    
positions = [] #output variable
skew = Skew(Text)
print skew
minimum = min(skew.values()) 
print minimum
#use the for loop, to look for i when Skew[i]=minimum
for i in skew:
    if skew[i] == minimum: positions.append(i)
positions = positions[1:]
print positions
```

"""That's my code.(Apologies first time user), but it doesn't do what I want. If you run the code, the minimum value is -2 and there are 2 keys with -2 so positions should have two results, not one. Can someone explain why this keeps happening?"""

Comment: Thats because you remove first result in position with this line: positions = positions[1:] .

Comment: @PiotrDabkowski. I see that now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first index is start with 0.

```
    positions = positions[0:]
```